# Getting results from a database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working with phpexcel but I have problem by getting results from a database.

I have next code :

```
    require_once 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
include "PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php"; 
session_start();
include("config.php");
global $kon;
ob_start();
$excel = new PHPExcel;
$excel->getProperties()->setCreator('Boris Jelic');
$excel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy('Boris Jelic');
$excel->getProperties()->setTitle('Orders');
$excel->removeSheetByIndex(0);


$cols = array('tijd' => 'A', 'shop' => 'B', 'products' => 'C', 'naam' => 'D', 'adres' => 'E', 'gemeente' => 'F', 'telefoonnummer' => 'G', 'email' => 'H', 'leeggoed' => 'I');
$list = $excel->createSheet();
$list->setTitle('Users');
$list->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(20);
$list->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(25);
$list->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(40);
$list->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(40);
$list->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(40);
$list->getColumnDimension('F')->setWidth(20);
$list->getColumnDimension('G')->setWidth(15);
$list->getColumnDimension('H')->setWidth(40);
$list->getColumnDimension('I')->setWidth(40);
$list->setCellValue('A1', 'Tijd');
$list->setCellValue('B1', 'Shop');
$list->setCellValue('C1', 'Products');
$list->setCellValue('D1', 'Naam en voornaam');
$list->setCellValue('E1', 'Adres');
$list->setCellValue('F1', 'Gemeente');
$list->setCellValue('G1', 'Telefoonnummer');
$list->setCellValue('H1', 'Email');
$list->setCellValue('I1', 'Leeggoed');


//za background
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:I1')->getFill()
->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)
->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFE8E5E5');

//stavljamo naslove bold
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:I1')->getFont()->setBold(true);

//povecavamo velicinu slova
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:I1')->getFont()->setSize(13);


//moramo prvo uzeti sve orders sa statusom 1
$rezOrders = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT 
                                 shops.naam as shopNaam, 
                                 GROUP_CONCAT(producten.naam SEPARATOR '\r') as prodNaam, GROUP_CONCAT(producten.id SEPARATOR '\r') as prodID,
                                 order_details.aantal as kolicina, order_details.leeggoed as leeggoed, order_details.id as ordDetId, SUM(order_details.aantal) as prodCount, 
                                 korisnici.ime as korNaam, korisnici.email as korMail, korisnici.id as korId, korisnici.prezime as korPrez, korisnici.mobitelBroj as broj, korisnici.mjesto as adres, korisnici.huisnummer as hn,
                                 korisnici.gemeente as gemeente, 
                                 orders.besteld_op as tijd 
                                 FROM orders
                                 INNER JOIN korisnici ON korisnici.id = orders.user_id 
                                 INNER JOIN order_details ON order_details.order_id = orders.id
                                 INNER JOIN product_shop_tt ON order_details.product_shop_tt_id = product_shop_tt.id
                                 INNER JOIN producten ON producten.id = product_shop_tt.product_id
                                 INNER JOIN shops ON shops.id = product_shop_tt.shop_id 
                                 WHERE orders.status = 1 GROUP BY korisnici.id");

$rowcounter = 2;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezOrders)){


    $prod_id = $row['prodID'];

   $rez = mysqli_query(
                $kon, 
                "
                SELECT producten.naam as prodNaam 
                  FROM producten
                 INNER JOIN product_shop_tt ON product_shop_tt.product_id = producten.id
                 INNER JOIN order_details ON order_details.product_shop_tt_id = product_shop_tt.id
                 WHERE producten.id IN (" . str_replace("\r", ", ", $prod_id) . ")
                "
            );
/*echo "Product i kolicina : " . $redAan["productNaam"] . " - " . $redAan["kolicina"] . "<br />";*/
  $tijd = $row["tijd"];
  $ime = $row["korNaam"] . " " . $row["korPrez"];
  $email = $row["korMail"];
  $telNummer = $row["broj"];
  $gemeente = $row["gemeente"];
  $adresa = $row["adres"] . " " . $row["hn"];
  $leegoed = $row["leeggoed"];

  $list->setCellValue('A'.$rowcounter, $tijd);
  $list->setCellValue('B'.$rowcounter, $row['shopNaam']);


   while($red = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rez)){
        echo $red["prodNaam"] . "<br />"; 
        $list->setCellValue('C'.$rowcounter, $red["prodNaam"]."\r");
        $list->getStyle('C'.$rowcounter)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
   }


  $list->setCellValue('D'.$rowcounter, $ime);
  $list->setCellValue('E'.$rowcounter, $adresa);
  $list->setCellValue('F'.$rowcounter, $gemeente);
  $list->setCellValue('G'.$rowcounter, $telNummer);
  $list->setCellValue('H'.$rowcounter, $email);
  $list->setCellValue('I'.$rowcounter, $leegoed);
  $rowcounter++;
}


$writer = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($excel);
$writer->save('files/users.xlsx');
```

In $prod_id in a while loop I get all id's of a products but because I use GROUP_CONCAT in my query (*I use it because I need such a display in my excel file*) I do not get them separately, but grouped. And now I can't get the quantity of those product.

My tables in a database are as follows :

Order_details table (there is the quantity(*aantal*) which I need)

```
+---+----------+--------------------+----------+--------+
|id | order_id | product_shop_tt_id | leeggoed | aantal |
+---+----------+--------------------+----------+--------+
|180|       87 |                51  |          |    2   |
|181|       87 |                52  |          |    3   |
|182|       88 |                32  |          |    2   |
|183|       88 |                35  |          |    5   |
|184|       88 |                55  |          |    3   |
+---+----------+--------------------+----------+--------+
```

Then my product_shop_tt table which is connected with order_details table and products table :

```
+--+------------+---------+-------+
|id| product_id | shop_id | price |
+--+------------+---------+-------+
|32|          1 |      20 |  25.8 |
|33|          5 |      20 |  13.6 |
|34|          4 |      18 |       |
|35|         26 |      20 |       |
|36|         27 |      18 |       |
+--+------------+---------+-------+
```

And at the end my products table :

```
+--+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------+---------+--------+
|id| naam                    | details                 | keywords        | type_id | active |
+--+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------+---------+--------+
| 1| Test promjena           | Ovdje idu detalji       | Ovo su keywords |       2 |      1 |
| 4| Test                    | Ovo je opis proizvoda:) | rijec. rijec1   |       2 |      1 |
| 5| ime_proizvoda           | detalji                 | keywords        |       2 |      1 |
|26| neko meso recimo (50gr) |                         |                 |       2 |      0 |
+--+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------+---------+--------+
```

In $red I do not fetch anything because my $prod_id is grouped. How can I get all id's of the products separately, but my $rezOrders query must give the same result?

Result which I get in my excel file is as follows(*this is result that I want to get*) :

```
+---------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+
| Tijd                | Shop                    | Products                | Naam en voornaam | Adres             | Gemeente | Telefoonnummer |
+---------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+
| 2015-08-15 14:11:56 | Bakkerìj Van Hecke      | Test promjena           | Borís Jelic      | Krijgsgraat 130   | Gent     |      486386069 |
|                     | neko meso recimo (50gr) |                         |                  |                   |          |                |
|                     | buffon                  |                         |                  |                   |          |                |
+---------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+  
| 2015-08-15 14:11:14 | Lidl                    | prod1                   | Mesanovic Maida  | Krihuisstraat 130 | Brussel  |      486742185 |
|                     |                         | prod2                   |                  |                   |          |                |
+---------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+
```

What I'm trying to do is to write next to each product his quantity which is located in order_details table.

When I change in my first query GROUB BY order_details.id then I can get quantity values from order_details for each product separately, but now i do not get the right display in my excel file. I get for each product a new row but I want to get it like on the first photo. Now I get it as fallows 
[image]

Comment: Does `$row['prodID']` contain the correct value? You are not selecting the field `prodID` in your SELECT statement.

Comment: @mario.klump My bad. Yes, yes. There is in the code, I just did not copy it. The problem is the same.

Comment: Try `echo`ing out all of your SQL queries and running them through phpMyAdmin. If they work, the problem probably lies somewhere in the way you're setting or concatenating you variables.

Comment: To my way of thinking, and to a rough approximation, there is no problem in SQL for which GROUP_CONCAT() is the solution - especially where you have a presentation layer (such as PHP) within which you can parse the results. But that aside, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry There is no problem with GROUP_CONCAT(). The first query givey what I want. But in the second one I need to connect those three tables and I need to get quantity for all products from order_details table. There I have a problem. I can't get quantity for all products. I convert it to a excel file, I can post what I get in that excel file. Would that help?

Comment: It wouldn't help me. But anyway, the second query seems to be essentially a repeat of the first query, so I don't understand why you need it at all.

Comment: In the second query I'm trying to get quantities for all products.

Comment: Why aren't you adding `SUM(order_details.aantal) as prodCount,` to your first query to get the product quantity? So you can access via `$row['prodCount']` and don't have to do additional queries in your while loop.

Comment: The result I get is total quantity sum of a products. But I need quantity for each product. With ` echo $row['prodCount'] . "<br />";` I get 10 and then 5.

Comment: @mario.klump I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your prodId is a string containing `"id1\rid2\rid3"`. If replace all `"\r"`'s wit `", "` and use the SQL `IN ()` statement instead of `=`.

Replace:

```
WHERE producten.id = " . $prod_id . "
```

with:

```
WHERE producten.id IN (" . str_replace("\r", ", ", $prod_id) . ")
```

Comment: I' m trying actually to export everything to a excel file. I updated my question. I added your code, but now I get only one product for a user in the excel file never mind that he's got a couple of them. Now I have problem in **$rowcounter** in the second while loop. Because it seems that every new product is stored over the previous one.

Comment: So you just change your question even though I gave you a solution? This site works because people score correct answers. If you keep changing your question instead of asking new ones the site does not work as intended. As to your new questions: good luck, but I only answers questions of people who work the system and get me the points I am due.

Comment: But your code doesn' work. I updated your my question because I wanted you to see what I did. I had no bad intention.

Comment: I am sure you have no bad intention, I am just explaining how the system works and hope you will learn. Don't expect people on this site to write the code for you, people just help to fix a specific problem if they think it is interesting to do so or the solution is simple. Take care to isolate your current problem from any other problems you have and describe the situation well and you will get help. Changing the question after the original problem is solved is not a motivator for people to help you.

Comment: I didn't expect that someone else will write code for me. I tried your solution and it didn't work and then I pasted my new code and asked you to help me further. If you want I'm going to paste old code, I'm thankfull because you try to help me I do not want to insult you. That was my original problem, I didn't change it. I wanted to get more products in one excel row, grouped by user and shop. That was the problem at the beginning and that is still the problem.

Comment: I solved my problem. I changed the content in my while loop `$prodAndKol = $red["prodNaam"] . " --- x" . $red["kolicina"] . "\r";
   $prods = $prods . $prodAndKol;
   
   
   $list->setCellValue('C'.$rowcounter, $prods);
     $list->getStyle('C'.$rowcounter)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);` Your code worked, I have only change my while loop.